# How to interpret asymmetric error bars?

Tags: data-visualization, standard-error

I got this data from an unknown source and I was trying to understand why the error bars (which I think represent the standard error) are asymmetrical. Is it because the y-axis is on a log scale? The data represents a time series (x-axis is time), and the number of replicates per time is probably 2 or 3.

[image]

Comment: Yes it looks like to me they may be symmetric on a linear scale. What kind of answer do you want though? The best others could provide is speculation based on the limited information you provided. The varying widths suggest that the replicates are not even for each category on the X axis, or the variability is dramatic within some of the bins. What significance does 1,000 need an additional line to symbolize for? Surely you have more info.

Comment: I think the variability is very high in some bins. The 10^3 line signifies the limit of detection of the experiment. I guess I just wanted to know if asymmetric error bars are indicative of a log axis, or if there was some other reason.

Comment: The Y axis is clearly labelled in the log scale, so there is not much room for debate around that question. For example of some random speculation, the bars are not necessarily error bars at all, they could symbolize say the range of the observations, and the line *could be* based on a theoretical model, and not the data at all! I'm sure you could dream up other scenarios. Not much to go on without other meta-data and how the bars are calculate or what they represent.